# How to change this jquery fiddle to have the first div open/active by default?

Tags: jquery

I found this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/m6aRW/109/) that does exactly what I need it to do for me. However, how can I alter it so that #div1 is open on page load? Just using display:block keeps that div open even if you click the others.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target'); //id of the element to show/hide.

        //Show the element if nothing is shown.
        if ($('.active').length === 0) {
            $(itemid).slideDown();
            $(itemid).addClass('active');

            //Hide the element if it is shown.
        } else if (itemid == "#" + $('.active').attr('id')) {
            $('.active').slideUp();
            $(itemid).removeClass('active');

            //Otherwise, switch out the current element for the next one sequentially.
        } else {
            $('.active').slideUp(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                if ($(".targetDiv:animated").length === 0) {
                    $(itemid).slideDown();
                    $(itemid).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>

<a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>

<a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>

<a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the first `showSingle` element click event:

```
$('.showSingle:first').trigger('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6aRW/110/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to be visible by default when the page loads, add the `active` class to `div1` and change the css to be

```
.targetDiv:not(.active) {
   display: none
}
```

If you want it to slide down once the page has loaded, instead add some jQuery to do so

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#div1").trigger("click"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it!

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#div1").slideDown();
   $("#div1").addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6aRW/111/